# Why the filter in object array not works in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have this metod:

```
  pesquisar(): void {
    console.log(this.razaoSocial);

    if (this.razaoSocial || this.cnpj) {
      this.empresaDataSource = EMPRESAS.filter(empresa => {
        empresa.razaoSocial.indexOf(this.razaoSocial) > -1
      });
    } else {
      this.empresaDataSource = EMPRESAS;
    }

    console.log(this.empresaDataSource);
  }
```

the `razaoSocial` and `cnpj` is a bind variable ngModel
My array `EMPRESA` have two objects:

```
export const EMPRESAS:Empresa[]=[
    {id:1, razaoSocial:'Ciclo Cairu', cnpj:'12345678912345'},
    {id:2, razaoSocial:'Industria', cnpj:'789456123456132'}
];
```

But i apply the filter, for example: `Indus`
 in the field of html, was expected the object `Industria` has been filtered in `empresaDataSource`, but not.

the output log in console is:

```
> Indus
> []
```

Where is it my error?

Comment: You're using arrow function the wrong way. If you add curly braces, it becomes like a function scope, so you have to add return inside of it.

Comment: @Phiter thanks for your tip. But i no thinks tha is is a cause the my problem.
I will refactor my code for the function for your suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using arrow function the wrong way. If you add curly braces, it becomes like a function body, so you have to add return inside of it.

```
this.empresaDataSource = EMPRESAS.filter(empresa => {
    return empresa.razaoSocial.indexOf(this.razaoSocial) > -1
});
```

or

```
this.empresaDataSource = EMPRESAS.filter(empresa => empresa.razaoSocial.indexOf(this.razaoSocial) > -1);
```

Comment: I am sory, i had understood wrong your comment. With a code example, stayed clear.
it worked the this form, thanks

Comment: Por nada meu chapa ;)